# How to share Joomla Article through Whatsapp?

Tags: php

This is my sample article..How can I share this article through Whatsapp? 
[image]

Your answers will be appreciated..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## **Custom URL Scheme**

WhatsApp provides a custom URL scheme to interact with WhatsApp:

If you have a website and want to open a WhatsApp chat with a pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so. Opening **whatsapp://send?text=** followed by the text to send, will open WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text.

Here is an example of how to write this on your website:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

## And to add the link or icon

you can edit this file

```
root/layouts/joomla/content/icons.php
```

NOTE : **You should not edit this file**. Instead you should create an override for it by copying the file to:

```
root/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/content
```

If this path doesn't exist, simply create it and put the **icons.php** file inside the **content** folder. You can then start editing it according to your needs.

I tested this on chrome mobile browser and its working. 
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Whatsapp button for Joomla](https://yendif.com/joomla/item/whatsapp-button-for-joomla.html) plugin in my joomla! extension and it seems quite promising! Just install this plugin in your Joomla account backend so that you can easly share your article through whatsapp.

[image]

With the help of shortcodes you can also insert it inside the articles wherever you want with options to customise the title and URL.

Hope this helps you!!!